# Save lmer summary within a function

Tags: r, function, save, summary, lme4

I wrote the following function:

```
filename <- list.files(path = "path", pattern = ".csv", full.names = TRUE)

analyze <- function(filename) {
  dat <- read.csv(file = filename, header = TRUE)
  twolevel <- lmer(DV ~ 1 + (1 | item), data = dat, REML = FALSE)
  output <- summary(twolevel)
  sink("output.txt")
  for (i in 1:73) print(output)
  sink()
}

for (f in filename) {
  analyze(f)
}
```

Filename contains a list of 73 data frames. Unfortunately, I don't get the summary of each of the 73 analyses, but 73 times the same result. What is wrong with my code? Thanks!!

Comment: Try running your code line by line and see what happens in every line. For example, you probably meant to use `sink("output.txt", append = TRUE)`, because now you're just rewriting the file over and over. Also, why would you add a `for`-loop that runs `print` 73 times on the same object?

Comment: In addition to @Laterow's comment, move `sink("output.txt", append=T)` one line up, followed by `summary(twolevel)`. The `for` loop inside your `analyze` function should be removed.

Comment: Thank you very much, I forgot the append argument!

Answer (score 1):

As discussed by @Laterow and @nya, the changes to you function -

```
analyze <- function(filename) {
     dat <- read.csv(file = filename, header = TRUE)
     twolevel <- lmer(DV ~ 1 + (1 | item), data = dat, REML = FALSE)
     sink("output.txt",append = TRUE)
     return(summary(twolevel))
 }
```

And then run the command as

```
for (f in filename) {
  analyze(f)
}
```